# Setting up the visibility of tooltip in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, bootstrap-modal, antd

I am using Tooltip for showing validation message in my Form(which is a Modal).
[image]

I have a cancel button in the Form. When I click the **Cancel button** (*Cancel button isn't included in the below images*) and redirected to the index page, the Tooltip remains in the index page as shown:
[image]

The code used for tooltip in form.js

```
<div style={{ 'height': '46px', 'display': 'flex'}}>
  <label style={{ 'color': '#f5222d', 'paddingTop': '10px', 'fontFamily': 'SimSun'}}>*</label>&nbsp;
  <label style={{ 'width': '70px', 'paddingTop': '8px'}}>Customer Name:</label>
  <FormItem>
    {getFieldDecorator('Name', { initialValue: '', rules: [{ required: true, message: (
    <Tooltip visible={true} placement="topRight" title="Please Input Customer Name" /> ), }], })(
    <Input placeholder="Customer Name" style={{ 'width': '164px'}} onChange={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); this.handleChange(0,e, 'Name')}}/> )}
  </FormItem>
</div>
```

Code for Cancel button in index.js

```
handleModelCancel = () => {
  this.setState({  isModelOpen:false });
}
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: what do you do in case you need to make the tooltip not visible? where are you handling that?

Comment: If I don't need the tooltip , I dont use this `visible={true}`.
If I remove this piece of code, the Tooltip isn't visible on the Form.

Comment: no i mean in the dom. how do you handle it if the data is inserted in the form?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem.Here are some suggestions.
The problem is that the visible property in Tooltip remains true.

So first ,set a property for visible

```
 <Tooltip visible={this.props.visible}/>
```

Or before your redirect ,change the style for div to display:none.